# Emberjs not returning all records

Tags: mongodb, ember.js, sails.js, limit, resultset

I am using the SANE stack, which consists of [Sails](http://sailsjs.org) and Emberjs.  I am also using MongoDB as a datastore.

When I do something like the following on the Sailsjs side of things;

```
Parent.find(req.query.id).populate('children').exec(function(err, parent){
  console.log('children.length = ' + parent[0].children.length);
});
```

I get 212

But when I do something like the following on the Emberjs side of things;

```
parent.get('children').then(function(children){
  console.log('children.length = ' + children.length);
});
```

I get 30.

As a matter of fact, once the number of records goes over 30, it does not matter ember will only return 30 records.

Is there some way to get the rest of the records?  I actually need to records so I can sort and calculate some things.  I am not just displaying them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you verified that the request that is fired by EmberJS actually returns those 30 records?

Comment: Yes.  When I have.  When I look at the ember inspector it shows 31 records.  I think one of the records may be created client side and not save to the server yet.  But either way, it definitely is not returning all the records.  Is there some configuration that stop emberjs from bring back more then 30 records?  Maybe to guard against a result set the is 'to big' or something?

Comment: A good place to discuss in more detail: https://gitter.im/balderdashy/sails

Comment: @TravisWebb thanks.  I posted in https://gitter.im/artificialio/sane since that is the stack I am using.  But I will try gitter.im/balderdashy/sails and see if they have any advice as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Explanation

That's because the default response limit in Sails is 30 records. It's there obviously so that if you have 10k or a million rows you don't make some normal request and accidentally dump out your entire database to the client and crash everything.

This is documented here:

http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-blueprints

> defaultLimit (default: 30)
>
> The default number of records to show in the response
>   from a "find" action. Doubles as the default size of populated arrays
>   if populate is true.

It's also documented in the `config/blueprints.js` file in your sails app:
https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-generate-backend/blob/master/templates/config/blueprints.js#L152-L160.

Here is the relevant code: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/master/lib/hooks/blueprints/actionUtil.js#L291

#### Solution

1. Edit the `defaultLimit` in your `config/blueprints.js` file

**OR**

2. Add `&limit=<number>` to your http request URL

Comment: @Travis_Webb thanks!  I figured it was something like that and it is understandable.  However, when I am on the sails console, I can print out my 212 objects all at once.  They are not stoping at 30 records.  That is why I thought it was a ember issue.  I guess I may need to do some of my processing server side in sails instead of client side in ember.  Or, Is there a way to 'offset' in the http request URL? Bascially so you can get 1-30, then  31-60, ect ...

Comment: Yes because sails console does not use the blueprint limit. You're making this more complicated than it is. Just alter the `defaultLimit` and everything will work.

Comment: yeah, but that does not scale.  What if my result set passes the `defaultLimit`.  Then I will need to run my query against the 'limited' result set, then run the query against the remainder(s).  Is there something like activerecord's find_each or find_in_batches methods?  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html
This allows you to run queries in batches.  I have posted this to another question in case this is getting off topic.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31226883/does-emberjs-have-something-like-activerecord-find-each-or-find-in-batches

Comment: No, your query runs against the entire database, as you'd expect, regardless of your `defaultLimit` setting. I don't know why you're making this so hard. If you use `defaultLimit`, everything will work as a sensible person would expected it to work. There's no catch. Just use it.

Comment: @Travis_Webb, I appreciate your help.  I am trying to be a sensible about this.  I may be missing something but I think the concern I have is what to set the limit to, if my resultset keeps growing.  I think this is reason why  `find_each` is in activerecord.  This is what you said in your answer concerning my post concerning the defaultLimit. _It's there obviously so that if you have 10k or a million rows you don't make some normal request and accidentally dump out your entire database to the client and crash everything_.

Comment: I basically ended up making the `defaultLimit` 'unlimited'.  But something about that does not seem right.  I don't think I should have to make the `defaultLimit` 'unlimited' to deal with a result set that may continue to grow.

Comment: You can page through the resultset using `offset` and `limit`. It's all in the Sails docs.

Comment: I saw `limit` but did not find `offset`.  However, I was wondering if there was a way to specify the `offset` through emberjs.  But apparently there is not.  I may have to build that myself.  Just wanted to make sure that I was not making something that was already done.  Thanks again.